# Factory reset doesn't delete everything

Tags: factory-reset

I tried to perform a factory reset on my phone to give it to a friend of mine. However, I realised that when I installed Whatsapp, I can still have my chats, my photos and songs aren't deleted as well. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `/sdcard` partion is not getting wiped. You need to specify more information but I'm assuming you're using a Custom Rom or at least, a Custom recovery. A stock recovery will *as far as I know* wipe `/sdcard` too. Only a Custom ROM by default wouldn't do so. So there's nothing unordinary here. Boot into recovery (I can't tell how since you didn't mention your phone's model) and you can use the options there to wipe any partion you want.

Comment: Hello. my phone is a samsung s5, it has custom rom

Comment: Also note that for a really "safe clean", factory-reset won't be sufficient – you might wish to really wipe, to make it impossible to recover "old contents". Apps helping you with that can e.g. be found in my list here: [Safe Data-Wipe](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because there's cloud backup?
See, what will happen if after a factory-reset, a whatsapp messenger with different account is installed? What will happen to our conversations? (assuming there's no cloud backup)